# `Cannot GET /en/first` error with routing module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, routes

I'm trying to create routing module in Node.js & express and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

The error is `Cannot GET /en/first`

The point is to have many folders like the en, each folder with it's routing.
Combine them together in index.js and call it from app.js.

My files structure:

```
public
 -js
 -css
views
 -index.js
 -en
 --about.html
 --en.js
 --home.html
app.js
```

My en.js file

```
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()

//en page1
router.get('/about1', function(req, res) {
  res.render('about1')
})

//en page2
router.get('/first', function(req, res) {
  res.render('first')
})

module.exports = router
```

/views/index.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()


router.use('./en', require('./en/'))
router.use('./fr', require('./fr/'))


module.exports = router
```

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

app.use(router);  

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(require('./views'))


app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Live at Port 3000");
});
```

Also there is an option to use an array instead of routing like in the en.js file?

Comment: Make sure to give your questions clear titles that explain what the problem is. That way people experiencing similar issues can find your question and potentially, the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
router.use('/en', require('./en/en'))
router.use('/fr', require('./fr/fr'))
```

There shouldn't be any dots in the route.

**EDIT**

Regarding your second question yes you can use an array:

```
const routes = ['about1', 'first']; // array of routes

routes.forEach(route => {
    router.get('/' + route, function (req, res) {
        res.render(route)
    });
});
```

Comment: @GuyOren I have added the correct route for the `en` file, I don't know where your `fr` route file is though.

Comment: fr should be a folder next to the en folder with the same files in it.. but if the en will work so the fr should as well

Comment: No, did you try it, is it working for you? After node app.js in the cmd, I get the console.log, trying the browser and that the error

Comment: The error from the console, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

I don' think a router can use another router. Instead in app.js do

```
app.use('./en', require('./view/en/en.js'))
app.use('./fr', require('./view/fr/fr.js'))
```

personally I don't like your way of putting router files in the view folder as they don't define the view. They should be in their own folder.

For the question you raised in the end. The router is only a mini-app, and is there to make it easier for you to define sub routes. For example you can do:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})
module.exports = router
```

And load this in app:

```
var birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use('/birds', birds) // basically adding prefix to all the routes in bird router :)
```

The resulting routes will be */birds/* and */birds/about*

You basically need three things to complete definition of a route:

1. HTTP request method such as GET, PUT, or POST)
2. Route (string such as "/about")
3. Middlewares (functions with 2-4 parameter. (req,res,next)=>{})

You can do whatever you want to store them and construct the routes. Maybe you can have a array of objects that contains all the info and do:

```
arrayOfRouteObjects.forEach((element)=>{
    app[element.method](element.route, element.middlewares)
})
```

You can also have a function that construct the middlewares if you know what they look like:

```
function renderView(viewName){
  return (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render(viewName);
  }
}
```

And basically you have 2 arrays that stores all route and all matching view names. Loop through them and app.get them all.